# Magento2.0.7 Js and CSS gives error?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7, apache2

I have following **error in apache2 error log**

> Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.woff, referer: /magento2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/css/styles-m.css

Suggest some solution.

Comment: @QaisarSatti  nope it shows same error after doing changes

Comment: you are saying deleting the pub/static and then deploy not work for you? also set the permission for pub/static

Comment: after      `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`   **got error**
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Locale' not found in /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64`

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2316

Answer (score 0):

It seems like is the problem with permissions. Try to add all of the necessary permissions for magento 2.

I recommend setting the permissions as follows:

```
All directories have 770 permissions.

770 permissions give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group and no permissions to anyone else.

All files have 660 permissions.

660 permissions mean the owner and the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.
```

You should set as bellow recommended.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```